# Rails fabricator - how to get value from association field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, fabrication-gem

Let's say that I have a model User which has many Notes. Each note has the field user_name. I would like my notes Fabricator to  look something like this:

```
Fabricator(:note, class_name: Note) do
  user
  content Faker::Lorem.paragraph(1)
  user_name user.full_name
end
```

What I'm trying to do is set the user_name with the value from the full_name method from the User that already exists. But I'm getting the following error:

```
undefined method `full_name' for #<Fabrication::Schematic::Attribute:0x0000000a279c50>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: well it's saying that `full_name` method doesn't exist. I'm guessing that `user` is a `Fabrication::Schematic::Attribute`  object, perhaps the method exists as a class method but not in instance method?

Comment: `full_name` is a method in the User model ... and I'm trying to get access to the User object ... maybe I need to pass it as an argument in the declaration of the Fabricator?

Comment: When I create a new bogus note I'm using `Fabricate(:lead, user: myuser)` where `myuser` is a User object ... I expected that in the Fabricator declaration `user` is a User object ... apparently not.

Comment: where is `user` being defined?

Comment: Well, if you look at [link](http://www.fabricationgem.org/#!defining-fabricators) at associations you can see that that's how you declare your association.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found out eventually in the [documentation](http://www.fabricationgem.org/#!fabricating-objects) that there is an attributes hash I can use:

```
Fabricator(:note, class_name: Note) do
  user
  content Faker::Lorem.paragraph(1)
  user_name { |attrs| attrs[:user].full_name }
end
```